# Read Dead Redemption II - Game mechanics for skinning vs not skinning an animal?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

In Read Dead Redemption 2, what is the difference - in terms of game mechanics - between leaving a large animal intact for transport and sale\cooking, vs skinning it first and having the animal and pelt sperate?

For example, does this change the value of each component with specific vendors, or increase\decrease the spoil time, or effect the crafting items that can be made from them?